Influence of _cl tables on product import & incremental indexing
I use SQL Import functionality outside Magento 2 Bootstrap. It perfectly works, but I have a degradation. After 2M imported products daily import benchmark decreased in 3 times. After figuring out I got to conclusion that the problem is in _cl tables
Here is what I have in _cl tables:



Table
Record count




catalog_product_attribute_cl
135M


catalog_product_category_cl
66M


catalog_product_price_cl
75M


cataloginventory_stock_cl
62M


catalogrule_product_cl
154M


catalogsearch_fulltext_cl
171M


inventory_cl
4M



If I remove all data after every X number of imported products, would it properly work with incremental index through bin/magento cron:run. Would incremental functionality synchronize with ElasticSearch only data that appears in _cl tables & won't touch data that is already synchronized?

Yes, it would. I would would sync only data that was recently added. Finally due to large number of products & very stressful inefficient SELECT queries in Magento Index API we decided to refuse from using out of the box index functionality & implemented our custom methods for ElasticSearch outside Magento API

Could you please elaborate on how you did that?
